# Copy Function Javascript or Other iOS

Tags: javascript

I have a website at [www.hashtagsforlikes.co](http://www.hashtagsforlikes.co).
We have copy functions that work everywhere except for iOS. Please use the website as reference.

They currently work with JavaScript below:

```
document.getElementById("copyfit6").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("fit6"), "msg");
});
```

Is there a way I can get these working for iOS without resorting to an APP?

Comment: What does `copyToClipboardMsg` do?

Comment: Perhaps use this project as a reference. https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/